# Abstract shapes with irregular blur

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, gradient, blur, abstract

I would like to create different shapes with a similar blur effect, like a moving(?)

I have Adobe CC and would like to save them as pngs. Any ideas?

[image][image]
[image]

Comment: What have you tried?? Where is that failing?

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's not an irregular blur in Photoshop. It can be, but making it would be complex. It's simpler in Illustrator. This answer shows it there.

The grey background is inserted to show what's going on:

[image]

1. A white circle and a black circle - fill only, no stroke!
2. Blend with option smooth color.
3. a new black circle is inserted

The blend contains actually hundreds of shapes which have different colors. To keep the computer load manageable all must be rasterized, so

4. Select the shapes and apply Object > Rasterize > Transparent background, 300 ppi or more. Insert blur; apply Filter > Photoshop > Blur > Gaussian blur, a few pixels only or nothing.
5. Change the background to black

Instead of rasterizing in Illustrator you can copy and paste the shapes to Photoshop into as big image as needed to retain the sharpness. Prepare for ex. an empty 1000 x 1000 px image. Paste as pixels and drag the size as you paste, not later. Pasting as smart object is useful if you must scale it or you want to try effects non-destructively.

Colorizing is possible easily with a new layer which has blending mode Multiply. In Photoshop that layer can be painted. It's tried in the next example. The pasted shape is blurred in Photoshop:

[image]

The adjustment layer "curves" compensates partially the apparent contrast loss caused by multiply.

Comment: Thank you so much, this workflow helps me a lot!! Additional I play around with the "Radial Blur" FIlter (Effects -> Blur -> Radial Blur) in Illustrator. 